# Why aren't some of the PDF files aren't rendering in my Angular app?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdf

I'm trying to display the PDF file in my application using a package, "ng2-pdf-viewer" and I used the PDF URL they provided for testing that worked just fine.

But then, I tried rendering another PDF file, it showed nothing, a blank.

This is the code: [In app.component.html]

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSource"
          [render-text]="true"
          style="display: block;"
```

> 

[In app.component.ts]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  

pdfSource = {url: 'https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf', withCredentials: false}
}
```

[In app.module.ts]

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MathjaxModule } from 'mathjax-angular';
import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    MathjaxModule.forRoot(),
    PdfViewerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the link for the package I'm using: "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer"

And the PDF Url that worked is this: "https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf"

Comment: [src] (so pfdSource) should just be string of a url - you're giving it an object?

Comment: @MikeOne "For more control, you can pass options object to [src]", it's written in the Usage section of the `ng2-pdf-viewer`. If you pass this URL: "https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/assets/pdf-test.pdf" in the `url` key of `pdfSource`, you'll see it's working.